# App installation blocked with a pop-up saying app may collect data to track user

Tags: android, android-install-apk, google-play-protect

While installing the latest version of our app (outside of Google Play), a pop-up message shows up:

Installation Blocked
This app can collect data that may be used to track you.
Even if you have heard of this app or the app developer, it's still dangerous to install an app from an untrusted source.

so
What can make Google Play to detect an app harmfully?
How do we understand what's Google Play problem with our app?

Comment: To clarify: you side loaded that app (it is not coming from Play Store). Why do you think then Google Play has a problem with it?

Comment: my app isn't launched in google play but I have a lot of users.(Why do you think then Google Play has a problem with it) because it says that it's not safe to install my app.

Comment: Is your problem solved?

Comment: yes I write the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after asking form google support about my problem they said to me that because I using sensitive user data I should use SSL in my communication with my server and after update my app that message disappeared.
also, read this [link](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/3258249) it has great info about this kind of problems by google protect.
and if you think that google protect unreasonably saying your app is harmful you can use this [link](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2992033) to inform them

Comment: Hi, are you send email to google support. can i have that link ?